# Moving the 'center of the object' to the actual center...

Tags: sculpting

I have sculpted a model in sculptris (maybe i have done something wrong, it's my first time) and exported it to an object then reduced polygones and stuff, and now i have some stuff to do in blender but i noticed that the center of my model isn't really the center. It has moved to his left and idk how to move it to the right position. I have never used Blender before so maybe it's a dumb question. Here's an image of what it looks like:

[image]

I'm not a Blender guru so please be as precise as you can if you know how to fix this.Thank you for your.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the Center is easily done with the moster of a shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>.From the dropdown select

- *Origin to geometry* If you want to move the center.
- *Geometry to origin* If you want to move the mesh.

If you want finer grade control of the position of the center, you can go to *Edit* mode by hitting Tab, select all vertices by hitting  <kbd>A</kbd> and move the mesh with the widgets. The center doesn't move, so you can position the mesh onto the center like this.

In Object Mode you can center an object so that the center is at the center of the scene (by moving the mesh) with the hotkey <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.

I hope this helps.